# mustache.js is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I am try to use mustache.js for templating but my basic code is not working Pls help where I m going wrong-

```
var person = {
    firstName: "Christophe",
    lastName: "Coenraets"
};

var template = "<h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>";
var output = Mustache.render(template, person);
document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = output;
```

The above code is working but the below code is not working :-

This line is written in my .html page:

```
<script id="sample_template" type="text/template">
    <h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
</script>
```

This line is written in my .js file:

```
var data ={
   firstName: "Christophe",
   lastName: "Coenraets"
};
var template = $('#sample_template').html();
//console.log(template);  this prints the html content in console
var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
$('#result1').html(info);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: wrap your js code in `$(document).ready(function() { ...  });`

Comment: [@MrShibby](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3170216/mrshibby) their is no error in console and [@Skwal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2618490/skwal) I include $(document).ready

Comment: are you sure that the element with id="result1" exists?

Comment: yes this is the code <h2>Result</h2>
<pre id="result1">
</pre>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution i have both mustache server side and client side and the problem i describe above is that when i try to fill the placeholders at client side then those placeholder are already consume at server side(becoz i didn't sperate file which has to render server side and whom to render client side ). So their is no placeholder while rendering on client side so only i got html tags will display.

Comment: I was using Jekyll and this was exactly my same problem.  It uses { } syntax and mustache and jsrender use {{ }}.    Thank you thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, it seems that `.to_html()` is deprecated...

Comment: what do you mean by .to_html() is deprecated i try it using .render but it also not working

Comment: You could link to or quote from the document. You could also show the solution.
My worked solution is to just replace "to_html" with "render". Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as [level_0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21883079/7748370).
Django templating on the server-side also uses the same tag as mustache-js i.e {{ }}

Here is a simple example that gets past the Django server-side templating issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/2.3.0/mustache.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="target">Loading...</div>
    <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
        Hello {% templatetag openvariable %} name {% templatetag closevariable %}
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var template = $('#template').html();
        console.log(template);
        Mustache.parse(template); // optional, speeds up future uses
        var rendered = Mustache.render(template, { name: "Luke" });
        $('#target').html(rendered);

    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ended up in this thread as I did, because you googled for "Mustache.to_html is not a function", you can simply replace `Mustache.to_html` with `Mustache.render`. The first one has been removed, so you probably updated the library.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/evildonald/qK5NT/

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var data ={
     firstName: "Christophe",
     lastName: "Coenraets"
  };

  var template = $('#sample_template').html();

  var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);

  $('#result1').html(info); 
});
```

html:

```
<script id="sample_template" type="text/template">
  <h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
</script>
```

Comment: works with both to_html or render but as already said to_html is deprecated

Comment: On putting ur jsfidle example in my html file i get nothing as result and find this while inspecting elements using firebug -<div id="output">
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I use a templater hbs on the backend. I solved it by manually creating a structure in the middle of the tag.

in html:

```
<div id="messages"></div>
<script id="message-template" type="x-tmpl-mustache"></script>
```

create html:

```
const messageTemplate = document.querySelector('#message-template');

messageTemplate.innerHTML = `
  <div>
    <p>
    <span class="user_name">{{username}}</span>
    </p>
    <p class="user_message">{{message}}</p>
  </div>
`;
```

used:

```
const obj = {
  username: message.username,
  message: message.text
};

let html = Mustache.render(messageTemplate.innerHTML, obj);
messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```